# how to divide one window into two windows

Tags: interface, customization

I'm having difficulty dividing a window into two parts vertically. I know how to divide it horizontally but I cannot do it vertically.

What difference is there between the two?

Comment: Do you mean window as in the blender window?

Comment: Yes Lukas, like the tag indicates!

Comment: Oh you meant divide a area in the user interface, to have an additional editor? This is why proper explanation and proper tags are important. I totally misunderstood, I though you were trying to model a 3D window as in a building or something. Tags edited

Answer (score 4):

To divide the window vertically click the upper right corner and drag downward with the mouse.  The direction the mouse moves after you start the click and drag determines which way the window divides.

Dragging to the right breaks the window horizontally, dragging downward breaks the window vertically.

[image]